# Error while defining custom array/hash method

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

```
def [](index)
  case index
  when 0, -2: @x
  when 1, -1: @y
  when :x, "x": @x
  when :y, "y": @y
  else nil
  end
end
```

```
array.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
  when 0, -2: @x
             ^
array.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
  when :x, "x": @x
               ^
array.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
  when :y, "y": @y
               ^
array.rb:8: warning: else without rescue is useless
array.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

---

I am writing this as is from the book, The Ruby Programming Language.

My ruby version is ruby 1.9.3p0

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: The syntax of the `case/when` statement was changed from ruby 1.8 to ruby 1.9. That's the reason.

Comment: No, it wasn't. The colon syntax was never allowed, not even in 1.8. It just accidentally worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use the regular case..when..then form

```
def [](index)   
  case index   
    when 0, -2 then @x   
    when 1, -1 then @y   
    when :x, "x" then @x   
    when :y, "y" then @y   
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

try ";" or newline instead of ":".

```
case index
  when 0, -2; @x
```

---

```
case index
  when 0, -2
    @x
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked as well. I think the authors probably meant to say `;` instead of `:`.